# How do I stop MOYA/Alamfire from Escaping my body json parameters?

Tags: swift, alamofire, moya

I am using Moya with Alamofire. They are tightly integrated. However, either Moya or Alamofire is escaping my body json parameters in the POST request.

I am looking for where and how to prevent this escaping from happening.

Example:

```
{ 
  "credentials": { 
    "secret": 
jJWoBkc64O0VzcjRQv4MIuQv0HgRLiNQZL7GAhtINz6EKuaK+u+YkBMi9z3v6rqLBh8TD8lIO3F+5t7iJB/FJw==
```

See the `/FJw==` that gets escaped to `\/FJw==`

Comment: "is escaping my body json parameters" Could you be more explicit about that? Do you have a quick example? Escaping, you mean not putting your param in the request body? Or adding percent escape characters?

Comment: Your json example is broken, but I guess you omitted double-quotes. And inside JSON strings `\/` is a valid escape sequence. You have no need to prevent it.

Comment: it was a shortened version to show the issue. I need to remove the escape because it interferes with the REST service I am using

Comment: If the REST service does not work for a valid JSON, the it is broken, which is incredible. Or you made it yourself? Why do you think `\/` is the reason your REST service is interfered? Please show enough info.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this kludge worked for me for now:

```
struct JSONStringArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {

func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
    var urlRequest = urlRequest.urlRequest

    let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters!, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

    let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    if let json = json {
        print(json)
        let newJson = json.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\/", with: "/")
        urlRequest?.httpBody = newJson.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue));
    }

    return urlRequest!
}   
}
```

then in task

```
    var task: Task {
    switch self {
             case
         .postConnectAddress:
        return .requestParameters(parameters: parameters! , encoding: JSONStringArrayEncoding())
```